# Font-awesome icons not displaying in v-for loop in Vue, but rendering as HTML text

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I have to loop an element four times with a v-for, everything is rendering just fine, but Font Awesome icons are not showing up as icons, but as HTML text. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="second-section-paragraph-1" v-for="(el) in ideasDrawings">
    <div>
        {{el.icon}}
    </div>
    <h3>{{el.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{el.paragraph}}</p>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
ideasDrawings: [
    {
        icon: '<i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>',
        title:'First there is an idea',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: '<i class="far fa-comment"></i>',
        title:'Then we talk about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: '<i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>',
        title:'And we think about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },
    
    {
        icon: '<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>',
        title:'So we draw along',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },
```

Comment: `<div v-html="el.icon"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid `v-html` and instead change your `<template>` to

```html
<div class="second-section-paragraph-1" v-for="(el) in ideasDrawings" :key="el.title">
    <i :class="['fas', el.icon]"></i>
    <h3>{{el.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{el.paragraph}}</p>
</div>
```

and change the part in your `<script>` to

```js
ideasDrawings: [
    {
        icon: 'fa-lightbulb',
        title:'First there is an idea',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: 'fa-comment',
        title:'Then we talk about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: 'fa-cloud',
        title:'And we think about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },
    
    {
        icon: 'fa-pencil-alt',
        title:'So we draw along',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div
 class="second-section-paragraph-1"
 v-for="(el) in ideasDrawings"
 :key="el.title"
>
    <i :class="el.icon"></i>
    <h3>{{el.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{el.paragraph}}</p>
</div>
```

```js
ideasDrawings: [
    {
        icon: 'fas fa-lightbulb',
        title:'First there is an idea',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: 'far fa-comment',
        title:'Then we talk about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },

    {
        icon: 'fas fa-cloud',
        title:'And we think about',
        paragraph:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, conetu adipisc sed be et ore aliqua pleasure itself'
    },
   ]
```

icon: '**far** fa-comment',
icon: '**fas** fa-cloud'